# couldn't not recognize spring.datasource.driverClassName in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to config datasource in the `application.yml` for a maven project in spring boot 2.4.5.

I want to add some config in `application.yml` like:

(The following is in `properties` format, but the IDEA will convert it to yml format for me. So please ignore the format here. The main issue is these properties cannot be found in spring boot 2.4.5 at all)

```
spring.datasource.url=XXX
spring.datasource.driverClassName=XXX
```

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.imooc</groupId>
    <artifactId>sell</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sell</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I also imported all these dependencies.

The issue is when I tried to add the datasource config in the `application.yml`, it can not be found. The only thing I can find with datasource is jta related datasource (refer to the snapshot I pasted here):
[image]

As you can see, IntelliJ doesn't find the `spring.datasource.*` config at all. It can only find jta related datasource config. Could anyone tell me what I am missing here? What's the correct config for datasource in spring boot 2.4.5?

Comment: you're mixng java properties with YAML syntax.

Comment: `driveClassName` != `driverClassName`

Comment: The IDEA can change the java properties to YAML syntax automatically for me in the `application.yml`. I think the correct configuration here will lead to a correct hint of spring.datasource.XXX. As the snapshot I pasted, it is not configed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Ignore the driveClassName thing, it's a typo, I just revised it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the dependency in your maven/gradle file?

Step 1. Add the maven/gradle dependency in your pom.xml/build.gradle file

If you're using maven -

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're using gradle -

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'
```

Step 2. Build or reload your project.

You would see the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

After I change the spring boot version from `2.4.5` to `2.1.1`, now I can config the spring.datasource related properties. I still don't know why it can not work in spring boot 2.4.5 but to whom may encounter the same issue in spring boot `2.4.5`, you could try to change the version.